# derived class cannot overload private member in base class with that from another base class

Tags: c++

I am attempting to use multiple inheritance to override a private base class member.  The base class, `Base`, inherits the member `class_type_` from its own private base `ClassTypeBase`, which should make it completely invisible to any classes derived from `Base`.

The derived class, `Derived`, inherits from `Base`, as well as from `ClassType`, which has its own definition of `class_type_`.  Here's the code:

```
class ClassTypeBase {
protected:
    static const int class_type_ = 0;
};

class ClassType {
protected:
    static const int class_type_ = 1;
};

struct Base : private ClassTypeBase {
    virtual int class_type() { return class_type_; }
};

struct Derived : private ClassType, public Base {
    int class_type() override { return class_type_; }
};
```

However, even though `ClassTypeBase::class_type_` is not accessible from `Derived`, the compiler still claims there's ambiguity between `ClassType::class_type_` and `ClassTypeBase::class_type`.

From [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U4eqs0el2qySDaJa):

```
prog.cc:16:44: error: member 'class_type_' found in multiple base classes of different types
        int class_type() override { return class_type_; }
                                           ^
prog.cc:8:26: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
        static const int class_type_ = 1;
                         ^
prog.cc:3:26: note: member found by ambiguous name lookup
        static const int class_type_ = 0;
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this:  _"...Member access does not affect visibility: names of private and privately-inherited members are visible and considered by overload resolution, implicit conversions to inaccessible base classes are still considered, etc. Member access check is the last step after any given language construct is interpreted. The intent of this rule is that replacing any private with public never alters the behavior of the program...."_ source https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access   But suguest you add the [language-lawyer] tag for a definitive answer

Comment: Thanks!   That does answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the name lookup/resolution logic, the first thing the compiler does is resolve the name unambiguously. Only after the name has been resolved, accessibility is considered.

In your case, `private` inheritance of `ClassTypeBase` by `Base` does not come into consideration until the name has been resolved unambiguously. That is the key issue missing from your understanding.

I am assuming you know how to resolve the ambiguity since you didn't ask how to do it.